# \n and \r\n not escapping when they are printed in the browser

Tags: php7, apache2.4

I am not sure if this is an Ubuntu, Apache or PHP issue.

The following basic scripts do not render a new line in my Firefox browser.

1. `echo "this is not \n creating a new line";`
2. `echo "this is not \r\n creating a new line";`
3. `echo "this is not
    creating a new line";`

I am currently learning PHP and have no idea where to even start solving this. All I know from Googling is that the above 3 should work.

This works

4. `echo "this does <br> create a new line";`

**My setup:**

```
Ubuntu 18.04.2
Apache/ 2.4.29 (ubuntu)
PHP 7.3.7-2+ubuntu18.04.1
Fireforx Developer (Quantum) 68.0.1 (64bit)
```

---

Thank you @cmak.fr and @Mathieu for your answers. It makes better sense now. I also found this link after reading you reply https://www.webmasterworld.com/php/3127164.htm.

Snooping  bit further I found that the `<pre>` tag also works when combined with `\n`. Why is that?

```
<html>
   <body>
     <h1>Some h1</h1>
     <p>Some text</p>
     <pre>
      <?php
        echo "this is not \n creating a new line";?>
     </pre>
   </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Browsers render new lines as whitespaces. And they render multiple successive whitespaces as a single whitespace. If you want to show have a new line, you need to use HTML. Replace the `\n` with `<br />` for it to work or encapsulate your code with the `<pre></pre>` tags. I recommend you learn some HTML first if you're starting into web development while learning PHP. Meanwhile, I am voting to close this question as general coding questions are usually offtopic on Ask Ubuntu.

Comment: @Dan I don't see general coding questions defined as off topic in the help center. https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A new line inside the html source code is not displayed as a newline in a browser.
Take a look at the source code of your generated html pages, you will find your newlines

The html code of a new line is `<br>`

In short

```
<?php echo "\r\n"; ?> // Writes a new line in the output stream
<?php echo "<br>"; ?> // Writes the newline html code
```

Another example:

```
<php
echo "<html><body>A<br>\r\nB<br>C\r\n</body></html>"
?>
```

Will output the raw text:

```
<html><body>A<br>
B<br>C
</body></html>
```

A browser will display this

```
A
B
C
```

Answer (score 1):

AFAIK, lines break are made with `<br>` or `<br />` tags.

You can convert `\n` to `<br />` with [`nl2br`](https://www.w3schools.com/PHP/func_string_nl2br.asp) function:

```
<?php
    $line = "First line\nSecond line."
    echo nl2br($line);
?>
```